# Iterate over calendar weeks and fetch data per week

Tags: mysql, sql

i got a sql question.

Given this table structure:

```
user-id | isActive | start       | end
------------------------------------------
1       | 1        | 10.01.2021  | null
2       | 1        | 03.01.2021  | 01.12.2021
...
```

I need to do a query to see how many user are active per calendar week.
How could i do this with plain sql? A user is considered as active if the start date is before or within the calendar week and end is null or after that week.

I'd like to have something like for a given time period like last year

```
date                                 | amount
----------------------------------------------------
xx.xx.xxxx (monday per calendarweek) | <amount of active user>
```

Thanks!

Comment: A use-case for a [Calendar table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague on how you define whether a user is active for a week.  Is it on the first day?  The entire week?  Any time during the week?

In any case, the basic idea is a recursive CTE.  The following uses the logic of "any time in week":

```
with recursive cte as (
      select startd - interval weekday(startd) day as week, endd, userid
      from t
      where isActive = 1
      union all
      select week + interval 7 day, endd, userid
      from cte
      where (endd > week + interval 7 day or endd is null) and week < curdate()
     )
select week, count(*)
from cte
group by week
order by week;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c6b2ab90a588e7c9575fde84387456e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Ah, great! Got this working on a local v8 server. But i need to run this query vs a MYSQL 5.7 server and it looks like the `with recursive` is only for > 5.x. 
I wasn't aware of that. Is there a way to rewrite it to 5.7?

Comment: @Johannes . . . You are better off creating a calendar table.